# Google Chrome webRequest API and swf file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

For some reason I cannot see the HTTP calls made from within a swf file (video) using the Google Chrome webRequest API. I have two files: background.html + manifest.json. I do capture normal requests to example.com (images, AJAX, js), but do not capture AJAX requests made within a swf file on the same page. Is this possible?

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function interceptRequest(request) {
  alert(request.url);
}

chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(
  interceptRequest, 
  { urls: [ '*://*.example.com/*', ] }
);

</script>
</head><body></body>
</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "0.1",
"background_page": "background.html",
"permissions" : [
 "webRequest",
 "*://*/*"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Chances are that if webRequest isnt picking it up then maybe its going through the plugin.  Try opening up the developer thing (what is that called ;)) and selecting Network.  See if that picks it up, if not, then I guess your outta luck.

Comment: That's too bad. It would be useful to see all the AJAX requests made on a given page. Even those in a given swf file. I can see the requests using tools like Charles or WireShark. But I wanted to make an extension to help track all the external beacon requests made from given ads/videos for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by selecting "Log XMLHttpRequests" under Developer Tools Settings. Hope this helps someone else.